# Flutter-web: How to clear console?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-web-browser

From [Hide http status code warning at chrome developer console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51087410/17798537), does the flutter-web has a way to clean the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using:

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';
window.console.clear();
```